# How to use Fullpage.js with Scrollr.js at the same time

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, scroll, fullpage.js

I have a project which is using [Fulpage.js](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/) and I want just one of the sections of this project to be scrolled Horizontally.

So I added [Scrollr.js](https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr), but the problem is that, it does not work.

Here is a my code:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./fullpage.min.css">
    <title>Fullpage Animation</title>
    <style>
        body{
            margin:0;
            padding:0;
            font-family: sans-serif;
        }
        .temps{
            position:fixed;
            top:0;
            left:0;
            width:100%;
            display:flex;
        }
        .nemoone{
            min-width:100%;
            height:auto;
            display:flex;
        }
        .nemoone .storyBx{
            padding:100px 60px;
        }
        .nemoone .storyBx h2{
            margin:0 0 20px;
            padding:0;
            font-size:48px;
        }
        .nemoone .storyBx p{
            margin:0;
            padding:0;
            font-size:18px;
            text-align: justify;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="fullpage">
        <section class="section s1">
            <h1>Other</h1> 
            <div class="temps" data-0="transform:translateX(0%)" data-4000="transform:translateX(-300%)">
                <div class="nemoone">
                    <div class="imgBx">
                        <!-- <img src="img2.jpg"> -->
                    </div>
                    <div class="storyBx">
                        <h2>Horizontal Scrolling</h2>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
                        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
                        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.<br><br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
                        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
                        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.<br><br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
                        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
                        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="nemoone">>
                    <div class="imgBx">
                        <!-- <img src="img3.jpg"> -->
                    </div>
                    <div class="storyBx">
                        <h2>Horizontal Scrolling</h2>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
                        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
                        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.<br><br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
                        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
                        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.<br><br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
                        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
                        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="nemoone">>
                    <div class="imgBx">
                        <!-- <img src="img4.jpg"> -->
                    </div>
                    <div class="storyBx">
                        <h2>Horizontal Scrolling</h2>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
                        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
                        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.<br><br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
                        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
                        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.<br><br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
                        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
                        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="nemoone">>
                    <div class="imgBx">
                        <!-- <img src="img5.jpg"> -->
                    </div>
                    <div class="storyBx">
                        <h2>Horizontal Scrolling</h2>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
                        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
                        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.<br><br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
                        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
                        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.<br><br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
                        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
                        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        <section class="section s2">
            <h1>Another Section</h1>
        </section>
    </div>

    <script src="./fullpage.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./skrollr.js"></script>
    <script>
        new fullpage("#fullpage", {
            autoScrolling: true,
            navigation: true,
            onLeave: (origin, destination, direction) => {
                const section = destination.item;
                const title = section.querySelector("h1");
                const tl = new TimelineMax({delay: 0.5});
                tl.fromTo(title, 0.5, {y: "50", opacity: 0}, {y:0, opacity:1});

                if(destination.index === 1){
                    const description = document.querySelector(".description");

                    tl.fromTo(description, 0.5, {y: "50", opacity: 0}, {y:0, opacity:1})
                }
            }
        });
        skrollr.init();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

So my question is how can I make these two Plugins work at the same time together ? Is it possible or not ? If yes, then how ?

I would really appreciate any idea from you guys, thanks in advance.

> **Alvaro's Answer Update:**

Just like Alvaro says, in order to use these two plugins, I have to use:

```
new fullpage('#fullpage', {
    scrollBar: true
});
```

So when I do this, the horizontal scrolling works, but now the problem is, horizontal scrolling and fullpage.js vertical scrolling, works at the same time together!

In fact, horizontal scrolling at this section must be finished and after that, the other sections can come afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

The only way you can use both together is by using fullPage.js with the option `scrollBar:true` as in [this example](https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/scrollBar.html).

```js
new fullpage('#fullpage', {
    scrollBar: true
});
```

You'll need a visible scroll bar to make use of skrollr.

However you can also consider using [fullPage.js callbacks](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#callbacks) and [state classes](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#state-classes-added-by-fullpagejs) in order to fire animations. See this video tutorial here explaining how to animate things using CSS3 and fullpage state classes:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qiCVPpI9l3M

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but when I add `scrollBar: true`, the Fullpage and section that should come with horizontal scrolling, both scrolls at the same time. I mean, horizontal scrolling at this section must be finished and the other section comes after this one.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean but probably not a fullpage.js related issue :)

Answer (score 0):

here is live example. look at this.

try like this.

[skrollr.js and fullpage.js. 2 in 1][1]

```
  [1]: https://codepen.io/SomeOneOrAnyOne/pen/eYzZKMg


  https://codepen.io/SomeOneOrAnyOne/pen/eYzZKMg
```